# Why Does String Not Equal What Is Stored?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

This is a simple, odd question...

```
if(tableViewNum == @"One") {
        if ([drinkArray objectAtIndex:0] == currentDate) {
            [updatedArray addObject:drinkArray];
            NSLog(@"MADE THE ELSE1");
        }
        NSLog(@"MADE THE ELSE2");
    }
    else if (tableViewNum == @"Two") {
        if ([[drinkArray objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:yesterdayDate])
            [updatedArray addObject:drinkArray];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"MADE THE ELSE %@",tableViewNum);
        [updatedArray addObject:drinkArray];
    }
```

In the very first if statement I ask if tableViewNum == @"One"

But I don't go in that section of the if statement even though tableViewNum actually does equal @"One"

As you can see the very last NSLog all ways comes out as

```
MADE THE ELSE One
```

But if tableViewNum really equaled One it would have gone through the if statement not the else statement code...?????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't compare strings with the `==` operator. Use `isEqualToString` instead:

```
if([tableViewNum isEqualToString:@"One"]) {
    // etc.
```

… and the same for the rest of the conditions. You're already doing it right in the second block.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still getting used to Objective C after learning PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific, you shouldn't compare ANY objects using ==. This compares just the pointers. Use [obj isEqual: otherObj] or with NSStrings isEqualToString: as described above.

Comment: Thanks Mario for the in depth answer!